# Vite serving text/html mime type for javascript asset file

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, vite

I am running a nginx web server which contains the build files from the vite application. I can run this application locally in dev mode without any problem. The issue arrives when running nginx webserver and the assets files are not in the correct format. The `.css` file is working as intended, but the javascript tag in the generated `index.html` by `yarn build` has type module which is interpreted in the browser as `text/html`. This is the generated error found in console:

*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

Opening the network tab in the browser the request and fetched javascript is correct. But looking in the sources the javascript file is not present.

#### Network tab

[image: browser inspect console network tab]

#### Sources tab

[image: browser inspect sources tab]

#### Generated tags in `<head>` in build index.html file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manage management</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/index-5b6aa355.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-a7ac0d48.css">
</head>
```

#### vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  return defineConfig({
    define: { "process.env": env },
    plugins: [react()],
    base: '/',
    build: {
      outDir: 'dist',
      assetsDir: 'assets',
      emptyOutDir: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js','.mjs', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json'],
  }
  })
}
```

#### dockerfile

```
FROM node:21-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /front-end

COPY . /front-end

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build --base=/

FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine

COPY --from=builder /front-end/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  frontend-web:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./../front-end
      dockerfile: ./../front-end/dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: docker.env
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution":"Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts",  "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.html"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

#### tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

#### nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to **include mime.types** from nginx.

I used nginx:stable not alpine, so I hope it works in alpine too.

Try add `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` to nginx.conf.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```